# cannot start Hadoop daemons: Insufficient memory

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

At first I could be able to start daemons and run jobs properly, then out of nowhere, I cant start the daemons (start-dfs, start-yarn). After running .sh the terminal waits forever (as in the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpqaC.jpg). The only way to stop is ctrl+c. The logs hs_error_pidxxxx.log says something about insufficient memory (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLqIc.jpg).

I tried some advises found in sites, such as adding swap memory, rebooting. I still cant start the daemons.

Here're some in conclusion (in case someone might be confused due to my bad communication skill):

- My vm has 4gb of memory with about 3.5 free at first.
- I could be able to run daemons properly on the very same vm.

Thank you in advance for every help.

PS. I'm using Hadoop 2.5.1 with HBase 0.98.11 on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by removing "export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`/path-to-hbase/hbase classpath`" from hadoop-env.

If anyone knows what I did wrong, I would be really appreciated to know that. Thanks.